# Floating Point Division in System Verilog

Tags: floating-point, verilog, division, system-verilog, integer-division

I wanted to use floating point numbers in System Verilog using the `real` data type. I tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm getting `2.000000` where I expect `2.500000`.

Module:

```
module real_check(input [31:0]a, [31:0]b,
                  output real c);
    assign c = a/b;
endmodule
```

Test bench:

```
module tb_real_check();

real c;
reg[31:0] a, b;
real_check dut(a, b, c);

initial 
begin

  a <= 5;
  b <= 2;
  #50;
  $display("Answer : %f ", c);

end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing [integer division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers). When calculating `int/int` (`reg[31:0]/reg[31:0]`), the result is an integer. So, when you calculate `5/2`, you get `2.5` *truncated* to `2` which is then converted into a floating point (`real`) number as `2.000...`. If you want floating point division (which *doesn't* discard the decimal), you need to have your operands (dividend & divisor) be floating point.

So, to fix your code, your module needs to take two floating point numbers as input:

```
module real_check(input real a, real b,
                  output real c);
```

And in your test case, you need to declare `a` and `b` as floating point numbers:

```
real a, b;
```

Comment: What if I want a certain bits floating point? I mean if I want a float point a = 0.5, I want it 4 bits width. Can I get some thing like 4'b0100 ? I am building a lookup table for Newton-Raphson division. The table contains 128 24-bits values, value X = 48/17 - 32/17*D, which D is 8-bit binary and the region is [0.5, 1]. I am struggling write a .sv code to automatically generate the lookup table.

Comment: @ShuaiyuJiang you mean a floating point with a specified precision? So, instead of, say, 32-bits of precision (single-precision), you have 4?

Comment: Sorry, Let me simplify my question.  I wanted a 24-bits output logic a[23:0], and a = 48/17 (for example). I know if I just use logic type, the answer will be 2, because the remainder is truncated.  I tried use statement "real", and I got a = 2.823529.....  The question is, I actually want a binary logic out, not a real number, is there any methods to help me get a logic output of 48/17? God, my English presentation is bad, can you understand what I mean? TAT